# How to cast in the compareTo method to a Generic Class which Implements Comparable?

Tags: java

I have an Arraylist with type Person. Name is a class that I have created. In my mainapp I'm creating some Name objects, setting each name-object to a person object and then adding the person objects to an ArrayList. When I try to sort the list using Collections.sort(), I get a ClassCastException.

I can not see what the problem is.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Person<T> implements Comparable<Person<T>> {

private T name;

public T getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(T name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person<T> o) {
    return ((Person<T>) this.getName()).compareTo((Person<T>) o.getName());
}

}
```

Comment: Please show a **complete** example. What line causes the error?

Comment: the error is caused by the return in the compareTo method

Comment: `(Person<T>) this.getName()` is a `T`, not a `Person<T>`.

Comment: how to write the compareTo method then?

Comment: You should show the `Name` class and a `main()` method which demonstrates how you call `compareTo()`. For more tips on making a good code example, see [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value from `getName()` has type `T`, but you are trying to cast it to `Person<T>`. To fix the problem, you need to compare the names directly without casting:

```
public int compareTo(Person<T> o) {
    return this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
}
```

Now this will cause another error because the compiler doesn't know if `T` has the `compareTo()` method. To fix that, you need to add a bound to the type `T`:

```
public class Person<T implements Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Person<T>>
```

**Note:**

To me, this seems like overuse of generics. Why should `name` be allowed a generic type when `String` is the only natural fit? And why do you need a `Name` class? It is likely only a wrapper around a `String` so you should just use `String` directly.

Comment: It may help OP to refer to it as a "bound" (or an upper bound, more specifically), rather than "constraint", since that's what they are called in the language spec and tutorials.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. I had a brain fart and couldn't remember that word.

Comment: @Code-Apperntice you mean T should extend the Comparable interface.

Comment: @user3740970 Yes, you can only use a type for the argument to `Person` if it also implements `Comparable` because you want to call `compareTo()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `this.getName()`, which is of type `T`, to type `Person<T>`. I.e. you are casting a Name to a Person, hence the `ClassCastException` ("name is not a person").

To fix this, please remove the casts and compare the names directly. Ignoring null-safety, it would be:

```
return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
```

Note that class Name also needs to `implements Comparable<Name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your name a type? This looks a bit weird. Could it be you meant to do something like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        return this.name.compareTo(other.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: The Person class should be generic

Comment: It is an assignment from my school

Comment: @user3740970 but generic for what purpose?

Comment: Generic in what way? Are you sure you don't mean comparably by a generic? Maybe update your original post with the assignment.

Comment: @AndyTurner Since this is a school assignment, the purpose might only be to help students learn generic syntax.